# android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing an app and I had some errors. When I run on the tablet it gives this error, but when I go to mobile it works perfectly. I already tried to clean and rebuild and tried to reboot the computer but I'm still having errors.

See the code below:

```
private LinearLayout btSobre, btCatalogo, btDistribuidores, btCadastro;

    btCatalogo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btCatalogo);
    btDistribuidores = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btDistribuidores);
    btSobre = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btSobre);
    btCadastro = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btCadastro);

  btCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chamarCadastro();
        }
    });

    btSobre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent chamada = new Intent(v.getContext(), SobreActivity.class);
            startActivity(chamada);

        }
    });


    btCatalogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent chamarCatalogo = new Intent(v.getContext(), CatalogoActivity.class);
            chamarCatalogo.putExtra("conexao", conexao);
            startActivity(chamarCatalogo);


        }
    });

    btDistribuidores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent chamarDistribuidores = new Intent(v.getContext(), DistribuidorActivity.class); //antigo porem na terceira entrega

            startActivity(chamarDistribuidores);

        }
    });
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/quadrado_curto"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/btCatalogo">
```

And the others `linearlayout` is the same, the error that show me is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{....MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

The strange thing is that the error only shows when I run in tablets, and on a regular phone it's normal.

Comment: Maybe you should provide the `MainActivity` and show the line where this error occurs? I do not see a reason the current shown code to throw such error

Comment: the line when this error occurs is  when i try to cast the linearlayout:  btCatalogo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btCatalogo);

Comment: are you initialize views inside any method or just in class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the strange is that the error only show when i run in tablets, in regular phone its normal

Do you have any additional `layout-` folders declared in `/res`? My guess would be that you have another layout file sharing the same name in a size-specific folder (e.g. in `layout-xlarge`) which has `android:id="@+id/btCatalogo"` assigned to an `AppCompatButton` rather than a `LinearLayout`.

See also - [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)